# How to make required fields "not required" based on dropdown?

Tags: jira

I almost feel silly asking this, but I have to try:

We have a screen with a number of required fields. But if a certain selection is made in the dropdown, we no longer want to require them. Is that even possible to do in JIRA??

Comment: Version 4.1.2. We're looking to upgrade to 5.x soon though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [JIRA Behaviours Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.plugin.Behaviours) to change required fields according to a drop down menu, for example:

```
FormField dropdown = getFieldByName("My Dropdown")
FormField other= getFieldByName("Other field")

if (dropdown.getFormValue() == 'A') {
   other.setRequired(false)
} else {
   other.setRequired(true)
}
```

As @mdoar mentioned, the Behaviors plugin doesn't work well since inline editing was introduced in JIRA 5.2. A workaround would be using JS for the field for client validation and display (disabling the field), as well as a workflow validation script (using [script runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) for example) for server side validation.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know Behaviors did that too! Thanks!!

Comment: The Behaviours plugin approach is easier to maintain than using custom JavaScript in the field configuration scheme. However, neither approach works well with the inline editing introduced in JIRA 5.2